# WPS Office 32 bit for Linux

Tags: command-line, updates, libreoffice, database, wps-office

We need WPS Office 32 bit for Linux.

I am searching on web but i m unable to found any link of  32 bit WPS office link.
Please Suggest any link.

Thanks 
Shashi Ranjan

Comment: Why ask here?  What OS/release are you using?

Comment: I think wps office has dropped 32 bit support. refer this https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/07/wps-office-linux-update-adds-pdf-support-drops-32-bit-support

Comment: We are not a search engine. 32-bit systems have gone end of life anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Per [this article on July 8, 2019](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/07/wps-office-linux-update-adds-pdf-support-drops-32-bit-support), WPS Office dropped 32-bit support.

As such, you cannot obtain 32bit WPS Office anymore.